# Replace a stand-alone character in a string using .replace (Python)

Tags: python, string

I have the following string

```
string = "House or r or place or r or floor or department or r"
```

I would like to replace stand-alone `r` characters (meaning any letter `r` that does NOT form part of a word) with another string, such as `True`

I have tried something like the following

```
string_replacement = string.replace("r", "True")
print(string_replacement)
```

Which outputs the following

```
House oTrue True oTrue place oTrue True oTrue flooTrue oTrue depaTruetment oTrue True
```

Instead, what I would like it to output is

```
House or True or place or True or floor or department or True
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could split the string into words and then replace words that are only `r`: `string_replacement = ' '.join("True" if word == "r" else word for word in string.split())`

Comment: You could get a bit closer by replacing ` r ` with ` True ` (note spaces added on both sides).  That won't find the "r" at the very end, but that's the best you can do with `str.replace()`.  Using the `re` module instead, you could use a search pattern of `\br\b`; the `\b`s specify "word boundaries" which handle spaces, end of string, etc.

Comment: Use regular expression `re` module .. search a pattern and replace it using `re.sub`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub()` to replace standalone `r`s. (The `\b` in the regular expression refers to a word boundary.)

```py
import re
string = "House or r or place or r or floor or department or r"
result = re.sub(r'\br\b', 'True', string)

print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
House or True or place or True or floor or department or True
```